# simple Room query in Android app doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm following an Android development tutorial that uses Room to store data and retrieve it.

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
data class DogBreed(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "breed_id")
    val breedId: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dog_name")
    val dogBreed: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "life_span")
    val lifeSpan: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "breed_group")
    val breedGroup: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "bred_for")
    val bredFor: String?,

    val temperament: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dog_url")
    val imageUrl: String?
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uuid: Int = 0
}
```

and the following Room DAO:

```
@Dao
interface DogDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg dogs: DogBreed): List<Long>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM dogbreed")
    suspend fun getAllDogs(): List<DogBreed>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM dogbreed WHERE uuid = :dogId")
    suspend fun getDog(dogId: Int): DogBreed?

    @Query("DELETE FROM dogbreed")
    suspend fun deleteAllDogs()
}
```

The `insertAll` method works fine.  I can retrieve all data using `getAllDogs()` and the `uuid` is auto-generated as intended.  However, the `getDog(dogId)` method does not work.  It always returns null.
It's a simple query and I don't see anything wrong with it.  What could be the issue?

The query is used in the following code:

```
val dao = DogDatabase(getApplication()).dogDao()

val dog = dao.getDog(uuid)

Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Dog from DB ${uuid} / $dog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

The toast shows something like "Dog from DB 12 / null".

Comment: Make sure you re passing the right id to your getDog() method , so that it retreives the data accordingly , if you can also show the code that you re using to get the dogs

Comment: @takieddine parameter value is correct.  I'll add some code.

Comment: when you log the uuid , is it nul or not §

Comment: @takieddine No the uuid is not null, as it is also shown in the toast message.

Comment: try this instead Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Dog name is " + dog.dogBreed , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Comment: @takieddine, as dog is of type `DogBreed?` I have to change it into `+ dog?.dogBreed`. 
 As could be expected that shows `Dog name is null`, not because the `dogBreed` is null but because `dog` itself is null.

Comment: Do you know how to debug §

Comment: @takieddine yes I do.  I just verified in the debugger, dog is null.  That's why it also printed out `null` in the original toast message.

Comment: can you check if the dao is also null or not , you have to verfity from where the nullity start

Comment: @takieddine `dao` is not null, and can't be null for two reasons: 1) it is of type `DogDao` without `?` (and not retrieved from a java call) and 2) I'd get a `NullPointerException` when calling `dao.getDog(uuid)` if `dao` were somehow `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the `uuid`, which was supplied as an action parameter when navigating from a different fragment, was not the correct value.  It was the `breedId` instead of the `uuid` property.

Answer (score 0):

I used Room a couple of time but it seems your uuId is an `Int` type and you are using a `String` type in your query. As far as I remember you have to use `like` for sql queries.

My guess is that you have to use both `Int` values or `String` values but not a mixed of it. And if you are using `String` type use `Like` instead of equal.

`"SELECT * FROM dogbreed WHERE uuid like :dogId"`

Comment: Sorry, switching to String was something I tried when it wasn't working.  They were both Int at first.  I'll update the question so they are Int again.